# Dataflow pipeline from Cloud Pubsub to Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create and deploy a Dataflow pipeline to stream data collected from a Cloud Pubsub topic to Cloud Datastore. However, I keep running into errors as follows:
cannot find symbol symbol: variable DatastoreIO  location: class DataUpload

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as I followed the following documentation to import the relevant package - DatastoreV1 as well as followed the syntax of the sample code within: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/datastore/DatastoreV1

Any help would greatly alleviate the head-banging I've been doing for these couple of days.. Thanks in advance!

```
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.PubsubIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1;

public class DataUpload{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

        options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);
        options.setProject(projectName);
        //options.setStagingLocation("gs://my-staging-bucket/staging");
        options.setStreaming(true);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic("projects/{project_name}/topics/data"))
             .apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(projectId));

        p.run();
    }
}
```

**Update**: I've included the below line and got a new bunch of errors.

```
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreIO;
```

DataUpload.java:[30,14] no suitable method found for apply(com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1.Write)
    method com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.PTransform,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) OutputT
        (argument mismatch; com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1.Write cannot be converted to com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.PTransform,OutputT>))
    method com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(java.lang.String,com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.PTransform,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) OutputT
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

Answer (score 2):

Please add the following import statement, which I think you are missing.

```
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.DatastoreIO
```

You can find some examples and documentation for using this [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO)

If you are using dataflow 2.0+, then please check out these [java docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/), with some different package and method names.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Initially I used this line but there was some other error suggesting that DatastoreV1 was missing. So I added both 
`import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.DatastoreIO`
`import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.DatastoreV1`
and now I get another bunch of errors referencing the line that the method was called, that "no suitable method found for apply(com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.datastore.DatastoreV1.Write)" etc

Comment: I think the issue is that your PCollection data type does not match.

PubSubIO returns a PCollection<string>
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/PubsubIO.Read

DatstoreIO accepts a PCollection<Entity>

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO

You'll need to introduce a ParDo in the middle to convert from the PubSubIO's string value to the Datastore Entity object type.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO

Comment: Also, please take a look at the example here, you'll need to specify the dataset as well to write to datstore

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @alex, I guess there's a lot of basics I need to pick up for beam. Do you have any resources to recommend for beginners?

Comment: I recommend reading through example pipelines, trying to run them yourself and modifying them a bit.



Dataflow Programming model
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/programming-model